# How many non-clustered indexes on one table?

Tags: sql-server, performance, nonclustered-index

I have a table with 12 indexes with just one column which are added by EF automatically:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table_Col1] ON [dbo].[Table]([ColId1] ASC) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY] 
...
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table_Col12] ON [dbo].[Table]([Col12] ASC) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I used sp_blitzindex and I got a warning: 'Many NC indexes on a single table'. Therefore I am thinking about merging some of them.
Also, I should remove some of them because it is a big table and delete is super slow because `SQL` updates a lot of indexes each time. What are the criteria to combine?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table_Col1_Col12] ON [dbo].[Table]([ColumnId1] ASC, ..., [ColumnId12] ASC) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table_Col2_Col3_Col5] ON [dbo].[Table]([ColumnId1] ASC, ..., [ColumnId12] ASC) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Brent mentioned in his training 5 indexes are enough but absolutely it depends on the situation.

Comment: Are you facing any issue with these indexes? try running sp_blitzindex from Brent Ozar and see. Your question doesn't have a straight forward answer - It depends on so many things.

Comment: Why would you merge them as one index? What queries are you running? If you merge them into one index you'll have to satisfy all the previous columns in your where/select to even use it for i.e. column 5. One can wonder if you need the 12 seperate indexes, but unless these 12 indexes form a covering index together for specific queries, i don't see a point in merging them.

Comment: This is too broad a question, it depends entirely on the workload being run against your database

Comment: It depends on your queries. The merged index is useful to queries that specify leftmost key columns.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a good idea to merge them. A single index with all 12 columns is most likely not an adequate replacement. Each of those indexes were created for a reason, you should investigate and find out what those reasons are before attempting to consolidate them.

Comment: I am reading different things. But I am confused and I do not know how to investigate the problem with indexes.

Comment: You need to start by identifying and communicating what the real problem is. Having a lot of indexes isn't in and of itself a problem. What problem are you seeing that you think is caused by to many indexes? Is it a performance problem? Is it a specific query? Think about that, and ask another question on this site.

Comment: I found out EF add index per foreign key but I could not find when and I could not find how to prevent it. On the other hand, as I mentioned I do not want to merge all of them and I am looking for a tip about which one should be merged.